# Binding to XMLDataProvider in Code Behind

Tags: c#, binding, code-behind, xmldataprovider

i have a problem moving a XMLDataprovider Binding with XPath from Xaml to code behind.

Labels.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Labels>
  <btnOne Label="Button1"/>
  <btnTwo Label="Button2"/>
</Labels>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="bindings.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="XMLLabels" Source="Labels.xml" XPath="Labels"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource XMLLabels}, XPath=btnOne/@Label}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,276" Name="btnOne" Width="75" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="93,12,0,276" Name="btnTwo" Width="75" Loaded="btnTwo_Loaded" />       
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
...
private void btnTwo_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String Type = sender.GetType().Name;
    if (Type == "Button")
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button;
        Binding label = new Binding("XMLBind");
        XmlDataProvider xmlLabels = (XmlDataProvider)this.FindResource("XMLLabels");
        label.Source = xmlLabels;
        label.XPath = "btnTwo/@Header";
        btn.SetBinding(Button.ContentProperty, label);
    }
}
...
```

The binding to content of btnOne works as aspected "Button1". But btnTwo is set to an empty string. The Output shows no errors.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouldn't

```
label.XPath = "btnTwo/@Header";
```

be

```
label.XPath = "btnTwo/@Label";
```

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes its so easy ;-)